# Question about class and methods- create a object of the class inside a method

Tags: java

I am confusing when create an object inside a method.

For example in this coding; I am not sure why I am putting public void copiar(Ventana w) , why put this?? in the second method it's obvious because we are going to set this values to variables, but in the first method I don't have any idea what I am trying to do.

I hope someone can help me.

```
Class Ventana
{
    public void copiar(Ventana w) {
    }
    public void copiar(String p, int xx, int y) {
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Copy the values from `w` to the variables. `this.p = w.p;` for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is like Elliott commented above.
With this method with `Ventana` as parameter it is more practical to duplicate a `Ventana`.

eg.:

```
Class Ventana{

    private String style;
    private int height;
    private int wide;

    public void copiar(Ventana w) {
       this.style = w.getStyle();
       this.height = w.getHeight();
       this.wide = w.getWide();
    }

    public void copiar(String style, int height, int wide) {
       //...
    }
}
```

Probably, better to have the adequate constructor:

```
public Ventana (String style, int height, int wide){
       this.style = style;
       this.height = height;
       this.wide = wide;
}
```

And then have the copy method as:

```
public Ventana copiar(Ventana w) {
       return new Ventana(w.getStyle(), w.getHeight(), w.getWide());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, as it looks like you've not provided the full code, maybe you're trying to do this?

```
Class Ventana
{
   string p;
   int xx;
   int y;

   public static Ventana(Ventana w)
   {
      Ventana copy = new Ventana();
      copy.p = w.p;
      copy.xx = w.xx;
      copy.y = w.y;
      return copy;
   }
}
```